# Leaflet how to show map scale inline with attribution text?

Tags: leaflet

I want to show the scale of my leaflet map using `L.control.scale()` however I want to position the scale the same way as the Google Maps API offers. I need the scale to be inline with map attribution. I have attached an image below.

**Google Maps API (how i want it)**

[image: Google Maps]

**Leaflet (how it currently is)**

[image]

I am using the following code to create the scale and add it to my map.

```
L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply put the scale in the same corner of the map as the attribution, you can just set the [position option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-position) when you create the scale control:

```
L.control.scale({position:'bottomright', metric: false}).addTo(map);
```

To make the scale actually go inline with the attribution, you can create a custom control that includes both the scale widget and the attribution text. Leaflet is designed to be extensible, so you can extend the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Scale.js) for `L.Control.Scale` to just add what you need:

```
L.Control.AttrScale = L.Control.Scale.extend({
  onAdd: function (map) {
    var className = 'leaflet-control-scale',
        wrapper = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-attr-scale'),
        attribution = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-attribution', wrapper),
        container = L.DomUtil.create('div', className, wrapper),
        options = this.options;
        
    wrapper.style.display = "flex";
    wrapper.style.alignItems = "center";

    attribution.innerHTML = "My attribution string";

    this._addScales(options, className + '-line', container);

    map.on(options.updateWhenIdle ? 'moveend' : 'move', this._update, this);
    map.whenReady(this._update, this);

    return wrapper;
  },
});

map.addControl(new L.Control.AttrScale({position:'bottomright', metric: false}))
```

The example above shows a static attribution string before the scale. You can still use the normal options to position the control and set whether to show the metric and/or imperial scale. You will probably also want to create the map with the `attributionControl: false` option, to avoid the default attribution showing.

If you need to dynamically set the attribution message based on the map selection (like the normal attribution control does), look at the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Attribution.js) for `L.Control.Attribution` to see what extra functionality you need to incorporate into the custom control.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue and solved it using some css trickery. Simply add the scale to the bottom right:

```
L.control.scale({position:'bottomright', imperial: false}).addTo(map);
```

and add the following css:

```
.leaflet-control-container .leaflet-bottom.leaflet-right {
    direction: rtl;
}

.leaflet-control-container .leaflet-bottom.leaflet-right > * {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
    clear: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your css trick but if you have other controls at bottomright you end up like this:

[image]

In my case the following seems to do the trick:

```css
.leaflet-control-scale { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
.leaflet-control-attribution { clear: none !important; }
```

[image]